# FTP Mount in Linux

Tags: mount, ftp

I want to mount a FTP site on my Linux server.
I use the **curlftpfs** application to do this,  but after a while, my mounted folder is unreachable, so I use `umount -l 'dir name'` to unmount and mount that folder again. Is it a bug in **curlftpfs**?
Or is there any alternative application like **curlftpfs** I should use?

Comment: It can either be an issue with the application or an issue with the network connection to the site. The only way you can be sure is to test things with another site.

Comment: Perhaps your ftp session times out?

Comment: Does `dmesg` show anything useful? If it can't reach the folder anymore there should be some kind of error.

Comment: ... That said, ftp is a very insecure protocol and not great for filesystem work anyway. Do you have *any* viable alternatives?